# Win 10 connecting to SAMBA on raspbian gives "wrong password"

Tags: windows-10, samba, authentication, smb, raspbian

I'm trying to set up a raspbian server (yes pi) and use a usb drive to share via samba.

Basic setup with no authentication works fine from my windows 10 machine.

```
[global]
  server string = %h (Samba, Ubuntu)
  security = user
  #passdb backend = tdbsam
  #map to guest = never

  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  log level = 5

[guest]
    path = /SMBMOUNT/HomePiFreigabe
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
```

But as soon as I comment in the lines

```
 assdb backend = tdbsam
```

and

```
 map to guest = never
```

Nothing works anymore. no even guest login.
using a registered user pinedorus

```
[2019/02/21 20:48:05.953229,  3] ../source3/passdb/lookup_sid.c:1645(get_primary_group_sid)
  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for pinedorus
[2019/02/21 20:48:05.953590,  2] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:424(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: NTLMv1 passwords NOT PERMITTED for user pinedorus
[2019/02/21 20:48:05.953678,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:431(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: NEITHER LanMan nor NT password supplied for user pinedorus
[2019/02/21 20:48:05.954407,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:315(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [pinedorus] -> [pinedorus] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
```

And as guest?

```
[2019/02/21 20:54:58.041053,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:181(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [PISERVER]\[guest]@[GONDOLIN]
[2019/02/21 20:54:58.041368,  3] ../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:400(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'guest' in passdb.
[2019/02/21 20:54:58.041470,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:315(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [guest] -> [guest] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
```

However, the smb connect from local works fine:

```
smbclient //PISERVER/guest --user=pinedorus
Enter pinedorus's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.16-Debian]
smb: \>
```

and in the log file:

```
  check_ntlm_password: sam authentication for user [pinedorus] succeeded
```

Waht's going on? What am I missing? It must be something really easy and stupid I'm not seeing... Help wanted :-(

P.S.: after Andy set me on the right track (tnx!) and my Samba Server workd 100% fine with another Win10 PC, I want to refine the question:

What could cause a (former Win7 but upgraded) Win10 PC to use NTLMv1? I have asked my friend Google and found some registry settings to force NTLMv2. Will post updates.

Comment: On the windows side, did you enter your username as either `PISERVER\pinedorus` or `pinedorus@PISERVER`? Windows will assume your domain is local by default, and this screws with your username.

Comment: just tried both (didn't know about the user@server) just to make sure. And yes, same thing... "wrong password"
the logfile however sais this:
mapped user is: []\[pinedorus@PISERVER]@[WINSERVER]

Comment: Okay, then I think that error about NTLMv1 is the problem. I've never had to change the authentication version on Windows for Samba, so maybe you've done something unusual. Do you specify a minimum NTLM version in your samba config file or do recall ever messing with authentication settings in windows? Can you try another windows machine?

Comment: wtf That was it! It works perfectly from another Win-Machine in my network.

Comment: The other machine (the one not working) used to be a Win7 which was upgraded to win10 ... the working one has always been a Win10. Could that be the reason? Other than that I dont remember having tinkered with authentikation. Also another samba server in my network (older model NAS) works fine with both win machines...

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by changing a registry key. According to [this Microsoft Security Guidance article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793313/security-guidance-for-ntlmv1-and-lm-network-authentication) and the [this Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc960646(v=technet.10)) there is a registry key that controls what mode of authentication and session security to be used for network logons.

In

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
```

set

```
LmCompatibilityLevel
```

at least to three (3).

I have set mine to 5 now and all is working (including my previously existing NAS access).

How this got to be set to zero on my machine beats me however. It's a Win10 (formerly Win7) and that should have had the value set to 3 from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. LmCompatibilityLevel can be deleted as well. Doesn't exist in a fresh install of Windows 10/11.

Comment: Nice work.. I was struggling a lot for this issue